# bubble sort without for each php

Tags: php, sorting, for-loop

hi i cant seem to get this to work and i keep getting undefined error in line 8 and 11. Here is my code

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$temp = 0;
$name = array("Suzuki", "Holden", "Jaguar", "Toyota", "Hyundai", "Ford", "Honda", "Mazda");
echo $name[0] . " " . $name[1] . " " . $name[2] . " " . $name[3] . " " . $name[4] . " " . $name[5] . " " . $name[6] . " " . $name[7] . "<p>";
for ($incount = 0; $incount <= 7; $incount++) {
    if ($name[$incount] > $name[$incount + 1]) {
        $temp = $name[$incount];
        $name[$incount] = $name[$incount + 1];
        $name[$incount + 1] = $temp;
        echo $name[0] . " " . $name[1] . " " . $name[2] . " " . $name[3] . " " . $name[4] . " " . $name[5] . " " . $name[6] . " " . $name[7] . $count++ . "<p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: There has to be a reason - why aren't you using `sort()`?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Apart from the error, you are not using the correct algorithm for bubble sort. It needs two loops instead of one. Check my answer below for bubble sort implementation in your case

Comment: Didn't my answer solve your bubble sort question fully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is mistake:

```
$name[$incount] > $name[$incount + 1]
```

when `$incount = 7` then `$incount +1 = 8` what is undefined for you... because you defined just 7 elements...

solution can be just `$incount < 7`

Comment: you have correctly pointed out the undefined index error. But the algorithm the OP is trying to implement still is not correct. He needs to use two for loops instead of one for bubble sort

Comment: Yeah you are definetly right... but he was asking about undefined error... and actually it is quite sad to see that such elementary algorithm is written incorrect...

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct algorithm for bubble sort. It needs two loops.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$temp = 0;
$name = array("Suzuki", "Holden", "Jaguar", "Toyota", "Hyundai", "Ford", "Honda", "Mazda");
echo $name[0] . " " . $name[1] . " " . $name[2] . " " . $name[3] . " " . $name[4] . " " . $name[5] . " " . $name[6] . " " . $name[7] . "<p>";
for ($incount = 0; $incount <= 7; $incount++) {
    for ($innercount = $incount+1; $innercount <= 7; $innercount++) {
        if ($name[$incount] > $name[$innercount]) {
            $temp = $name[$incount];
            $name[$incount] = $name[$innercount];
            $name[$innercount] = $temp;
            echo $name[0] . " " . $name[1] . " " . $name[2] . " " . $name[3] . " " . $name[4] . " " . $name[5] . " " . $name[6] . " " . $name[7] . $count++ . "<p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$temp = 0;
$name = array("Suzuki", "Holden", "Jaguar", "Toyota", "Hyundai", "Ford", "Honda", "Mazda");
echo $name[0] . " " . $name[1] . " " . $name[2] . " " . $name[3] . " " . $name[4] . " " . $name[5] . " " . $name[6] . " " . $name[7] . "<p>";
for ($incount = 0; $incount < 8; $incount++) {
    if(isset($name[$incount + 1]))
    if ($name[$incount] > $name[$incount + 1]) {
        $temp = $name[$incount];
        $name[$incount] = $name[$incount + 1];
        $name[$incount + 1] = $temp;}
        echo $name[0] . " " . $name[1] . " " . $name[2] . " " . $name[3] . " " . $name[4] . " " . $name[5] . " " . $name[6] . " " . $name[7] . $count++ . "<p>";

}
?>
```

But
Better Use

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$temp = 0;
$name = array("Suzuki", "Holden", "Jaguar", "Toyota", "Hyundai", "Ford", "Honda", "Mazda");
foreach($name as $f) echo $f." ";
echo "<p>";
for ($incount = 0; $incount < 8; $incount++) {
    if(isset($name[$incount + 1]))
    if ($name[$incount] > $name[$incount + 1]) {
        $temp = $name[$incount];
        $name[$incount] = $name[$incount + 1];
        $name[$incount + 1] = $temp;}
        foreach($name as $f) echo $f." ";
        echo  $count++ . "<p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't really address the basic flaw - you've just coded around it.